# Does closedness imply weakly sequentially closedness?

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $X$ be a normed vector space and $M$ a subset.
I have proved that if $M$ is weakly sequentially closed then it is closed, but I am wondering whether the converse is true or not?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

No, the unit sphere in $\ell^2(\Bbb{N})$ is dense in the closed unit ball w.r.t. weak sequential convergence (and hence not closed w.r.t. weak sequential convergence), but closed w.r.t. the norm topology.

But if $M$ is **convex** and closed, then it is also weakly closed and hence also closed w.r.t. weak sequential convergence, see e.g. 
 [Mazur's Lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mazur%27s_lemma) and [Convex set weakly closed if and only if strongly closed as well](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1151148/convex-set-weakly-closed-if-and-only-if-strongly-closed-as-well).