# Sobolev space $H^1_0$ weakly closed

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces

Let $\{u_n\}$ be a sequence of functions in $H^1_0(\Omega)$ such that $u_n$ converges weakly to $u\in H^1(\Omega)$.

Then, can I conclude that $u$ is in fact in $H^1_0$?

Comment: Yes, because $H_0^1(\Omega)$ is a convex set which is norm-closed.

Comment: @Svetoslav I just looked it up and you are referring to Mazur's Theorem I suppose?

Comment: Yes, this is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, because $H_0^1(\Omega)$ is a convex set which is norm-closed. -- [Svetoslav](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1449592/sobolev-space-h1-0-weakly-closed#comment2952783_1449592)

Reference: [Convex set weakly closed if and only if strongly closed as well](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1151148/convex-set-weakly-closed-if-and-only-if-strongly-closed-as-well)