# The set of w*-continuous operators is closed for the weak* topology?

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Let $X$ be a dual Banach space, i.e. $X=(X_*)^*$ for some Banach space $X_*$. Consider the weak* topology of $B(X)$, i.e. the topology of pointwise convergence on $X$ endowed with the $\sigma(X,X_*)$-topology.

Consider the set $B_{w^*}(X)$ of $w^*$-continuous bounded operators on $X$. Is it a closed subset of $B(X)$ for the weak* topology of $B(X)$ ?

Comment: Interestingly enough for the more general case of $B(X^*,Y^*)$ (i.e. for two different dual Banach spaces) the answer to this question in general is no, cf. [this counterexample by Jochen Glück given on mathoverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/a/349768). Of course this does not settle the special case $X=Y$ OP asked about but it might give some further intuition for this problem---after all the answer given below is flawed (as elaborated on in the comments below).

Answer (score 2):

By [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1832836/a-linear-map-sy-to-x-is-weak-continuous-if-and-only-if-s-t-for-so), you are looking at the set
$$
B_{w^{\ast}}(X) = \{T^{\ast} : T \in B(X_{\ast})\}
$$
which is convex.

Now if $\sigma$ denotes the weak-$\ast$-topology on $B(X)$, then $(B(X),\sigma)$ is a topological vector space whose topology is generated by the family of semi-norms given by
$$
p_{f,y}(T) := |T(f)(y)|
$$
for $f\in X, y\in X_{\ast}$. Hence, by a consequence of the Hahn-Banach separation theorem (see [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1313869)), $B_{w^{\ast}}(X)$ is closed with respect to $\sigma$ iff it is closed in the norm topology of $B(X)$.

But this last fact is easy to prove:

> If $X_{\ast}$ is a Banach space, then $B_{w^{\ast}}(X)$ is closed in $B(X)$ with respect to the norm topology.

**Proof:** If $\{T_n\} \subset B(X_{\ast})$ and $S\in B(X)$ such that $\|T_n^{\ast} - S\|_{B(X)} \to 0$, then we wish to show that $S$ is weak-$\ast$-continuous. To see this, choose a net $f_{\alpha} \in X$ such that $f_{\alpha}(y) \to f(y)$ for all $y\in X_{\ast}$. By the principle of uniform boundedness, $\exists M > 0$ such that
$$
\sup_{\alpha} \|f_{\alpha}\|, \|f\| < M
$$
(Here we need the fact that $X_{\ast}$ is a Banach space). Then for any $\epsilon > 0$ and fixed $y\in X_{\ast}$, choose $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that
$$
\|T_N^{\ast} - S\|_{B(X)} < \frac{\epsilon}{3M\|y\|}
$$
and $\beta$ such that
$$
\|f_{\alpha}(T_N(y)) - f(T_N(y))| < \epsilon/3
$$
for all $\alpha \geq \beta$. Then, for all $\alpha\geq \beta$, we have
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
|S(f_{\alpha})(y) - S(f)(y)| &\leq |S(f_{\alpha}(y)) - T_N^{\ast}(f_{\alpha})(y)| + |T_N^{\ast}(f_{\alpha})(y) - T_N^{\ast}(f)(y)| + |T_N^{\ast}(f)(y) - S(f)(y)| \\
&< \epsilon
\end{split}
\end{equation*}
and so $S(f_{\alpha}) \to S(f)$ pointwise as required.

Comment: It seems to me that there is a problem in the proof.  A weak*-convergent net need not be bounded in general. The net $(f_\alpha)$ in not necessarily bounded.

Comment: A second problem is the following, a closed convex subset is not necessarilly weak* closed.

Comment: The fatal flaw in this answer is that it is for the **weak** topology that closure of convex sets agrees with the norm topology, and not the weak-* topology (as soon as we have a space that is not reflexive). The weak-* operator topology suggested in the question is still different.

Comment: However, the highlighted statement in the answer (closure in the norm topology) **is** correct, although a flawed proof is given. As Zouba has pointed out, weak-* convergent nets need not be bounded. What we need is a version of the Banach-Dieudonné theorem or Krein-Šmulian theorem: For a normed space $X_*$, it is a Banach space iff every linear functional $\phi : X_* \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ that is weak-* continuous on the unit ball of $X$ is weak-* continuous on all of $X$. This allows us to restrict to bounded nets in $X$.

Comment: Trying to use the uniform boundedness principle can't be made to work because there are normed spaces $X_*$ that are *barrelled*, *i.e.* satisfy the uniform boundedness principle, but are not *complete*. If $E_*$ is an incomplete normed space, then $B_{w^*}(E)$ is not closed even in the norm topology of $B(E)$ (hint: construct a sequence that leaves $B_{w^*}(E)$ using rank-one operators and a Cauchy nonconvergent sequence in $E_*$).

Answer (score 1):

Over on the MathOverflow version of this question, I have answered it with [a counterexample](https://mathoverflow.net/a/352265/61785), $B_{w^*}(\ell^1)$ is not weak-* closed in $B(\ell^1)$.