# Prove that a weak continuous curve in a separable Banach space is a Borel function.

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, analysis, weak-convergence, topological-vector-spaces

I need some help to approach the following exercise.

Let $B$ be a separable Banach space and let $\gamma : [0,1] \rightarrow B$ be a continuous curve with respect to the weak topology of $B$. Prove that $\gamma$ is a Borel function with respect to the Borel sets of the strong topology of $B$. Is this still true if $B$ is not separable?

Answer (score 0):

The key is that in any separable Banach space, the weak and strong topologies generate the same Borel $\sigma$-algebra.  Recall that [a strongly closed and convex set is weakly closed](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1151148/convex-set-weakly-closed-if-and-only-if-strongly-closed-as-well), so in particular every closed ball is weakly closed.  And every strongly open set is a countable union of closed balls (by second countability), so every strongly open set is weakly Borel.

I am not sure about the non-separable case, but I would guess this is false.  I would look for a counterexample in a non-separable Hilbert space like $\ell^2(\mathbb{R})$ or $\ell^2(\omega_1)$.