# Element of weak closure by compact conditions

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, weak-topology

Let $G$ be a locally compact, metrizable and separable group, $X=L^\infty(G)$ and $A\subseteq X$ and $1\in X$. I know that forall $\varepsilon>0$ and all compact sets $C\subseteq G$ there exists an element $a\in A$ such that $\mid 1-a(g)\mid \leq \varepsilon$ for all $g\in C$.

How can I deduce that $1$ lies in the weak closure of $A$? In which cases does $L^1(G)\equiv L^\infty (G)'$ hold?

Comment: What is $G$?  What do we know about it?  What measure are you using to define $L^\infty$?

Comment: And you say something holds "for all compact subsets $C$" that doesn't actually mention $C$ at all. Please proofread your question.

Comment: In general, $L^1(G)$ is practically never the dual of $L^\infty(G)$.  I believe it's only true if $G$ is a finite union of atoms.

Comment: Sorry. I added some stuff. $L^\infty$ is defined via the Haar measure.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't true.  Take $G = \mathbb{Z}$, so that $X = \ell^\infty(\mathbb{Z})$, and $A = c_0(\mathbb{Z})$, the set of all $a : G \to \mathbb{R}$ satisfying $\lim_{g \to \pm \infty} a(g) = 0$.  Your hypothesis is clearly satisfied, yet $A$ is weakly closed and doesn't contain $1$.  (One way  to see this is to note that $A$ is norm-closed and convex; see [A convex subset of a Banach space is closed if and only if it is weakly closed](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1151148/a-convex-subset-of-a-banach-space-is-closed-if-and-only-if-it-is-weakly-closed).)

Generally, $L^1$ is practically never the dual of $L^\infty$, except in trivial cases, since the dual of $L^\infty$ tends to contain [Banach limits](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2017/05/11/generalisations-of-the-limit-functional/) and such.  In the case of metrizable groups, I think you could prove that $L^1(G)\equiv L^\infty (G)'$ iff $G$ is finite.