Weakly sequentially closed set in $L^p$
Let $\Omega\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be bounded and Lebesgue measurable, $p \in [1,\infty]$, and $a,b \in L^p(\Omega)$. Consider the set
$$
   K = \big\{ u \in L^p(\Omega):\, a(x) \leq u(x) \leq b(x) \, \text{ a.e. in } \Omega  \big\}.
$$
Is $K$ weakly sequentially closed?

In [1] the case $p=2$ was partially studied. In Fredi Tröltzsch book [2 - p263] the proof of the set to be nonempty, closed, bounded, and convex for any $p$ is presented as an exercise. In Manzoni et al [3 - p285] a simple argument is taken for proving that indeed $K$ is convex and closed.
Moreover, it can be shown [4 - Th 3.7] that if a subset $K$ of a Banach space $X$ is convex and closed, then it is weakly sequentially closed.
Up to this point, it would seem that yeah, $K$ is w.s.c., but in Manzoni's example it is argued that only the cases $p \in (1,\infty)$ are actually w.s.c. due to reflexivity, and there is a treatment for the $p=\infty$ case via weakly–$\star$ sequences. However, I don't see how reflexivity is a limitation?

I don't understand your question. You already seem to know that convex and closed implies weakly sequentially closed. Where is this concern about reflexivity coming from?

In fact, in your setting, one does not even need the completeness (see here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1151148/a-convex-subset-of-a-banach-space-is-closed-if-and-only-if-it-is-weakly-closed).

Thanks for the link @SeverinSchraven, I didn't know that fact about general normed spaces.
Regarding my question, I guess I am just puzzled that [3] stopped from concluding the w.s.c. for any $L^p$, making me believe there could be some reasoning for $L^1$ and $L^\infty$ to not satisfy the property, so I am asking if anyone can see what fails or confirmation that the set is indeed w.s.c.

I don't know how Manzoni proofs his stuff. Which part of his argument relies on reflexivity? Is he using for example the sequential version of Banach-Alaoglu?

I think the author got confused as they previously discussed weak* (sequential) compactness. In that setting you need reflexivity if you want to use Banach-Alaoglu in the proper form.

That sounds feasible. Indeed, they mention Banach-Alaoglu a little bit before.
Just for completeness, let me include the passage I am referring to after they conclude closedness:
Since $L^p(\Omega)$, for $p\in (1,\infty)$, is reflexive, then $K$ is weakly sequentially closed. As $L^1(\Omega)$ and $L^\infty (\Omega)$ are not reflexive, in principle we cannot draw any conclusion. However if $p=\infty$ and $\Omega$ is bounded, we can deduce that $K$ is weakly* sequentially closed.

There is no difference in proving this result for $p \in (1,\infty)$ or $p=1,\infty$.
To prove closedness of the set, take a converging sequence. This has a pointwise a.e. converging subsequence. (this is true for all $p$). Hence, the limit satisfies the constraints.  Then use that closed plus convex implies weakly (sequentially) closed. Also this result has nothing to do with reflexivity.

Thanks for agreeing on this, that was exactly why I got so puzzled about the mention of reflexivity!
